# Database of labeled voice data, specifically laughter

Tags: audio

I'm interested in building a tool for extracting regions of laughter from sound files. Can anyone give me a sense for what publicly available datasets I might use for training such a model?

Answer (score 5):

Try freesound.org - it has a large library of, uh, free sounds in WAV format: http://freesound.org/search/?q=laughter